# Error trying to set auto back up Firestore, cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am following this tutorial here: [Tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#gcp-console_1)

everything seems ok and it allows me to do everything in the tutorial, but when I run the function I get this error.

```
textPayload: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined
    at peg$parsetemplate (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplateParser.js:304:17)
    at Object.peg$parse [as parse] (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplateParser.js:633:18)
    at new PathTemplate (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplate.js:55:54)
    at segments.forEach.segment (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplate.js:120:29)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PathTemplate.render (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplate.js:114:23)
    at FirestoreAdminClient.databasePath (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_admin_client.js:904:57)
    at exports.scheduledFirestoreExport (/workspace/index.js:13:31)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:330:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

```
insertId: "000000-8410c5c7-8304-42b6-b2b6-dd55a54e8cab"
resource: {2}
timestamp: "2020-07-11T18:14:35.981Z"
severity: "ERROR"
labels: {1}
logName: "projects/b-b-b-app/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"
trace: "projects/b-b-b-app/traces/d7c07a715d0106225d9963ce2a046489"
receiveTimestamp: "2020-07-11T18:14:44.813410062Z"
}
```

I can't see what the problem may be.
I changed the buckets and the app ids like asked in the tutorial.

I am on a Blaze plan and can export the database to the bucket manually by using shell command and using

> gcloud firestore export gs://bbbdata-backup

I am using the GCP console on the firebase site and using this code.

```
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();

const bucket = 'gs://bbbdata-backup'

exports.scheduledFirestoreExport = (event, context) => {
const databaseName = client.databasePath(
process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
'(default)'
);

return client
 .exportDocuments({
  name: databaseName,
  outputUriPrefix: bucket,
  // Leave collectionIds empty to export all collections
  // or define a list of collection IDs:
  // collectionIds: ['users', 'posts']
  collectionIds: [],
})
.then(responses => {
  const response = responses[0];
  console.log(`Operation Name: ${response['name']}`);
  return response;
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
};
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the minimal exact code with which anyone can reproduce the problem. A link to documentation (or other off-site resources) is not good enough. The exact reproduction should be in the question itself. It typically also helps to know if your project is on a paid plan, or on Firebase's free plan.

Comment: Cheers for the heads up Frank I have changed it

Answer (score 1):

Following the tutorial referred by the OP I run into precisely the same error. Runtime used: `Node.js 14`.

Root cause of the issue: value of `process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT` is undefined.

Workaround: Go to GCP console -> Home. Note your `Project ID`. Replace `process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT` with the '`Project ID`' string. The Cloud Function will then work as expected

Note: it appears to be a known issue that `GCLOUD_PROJECT` environment variable was missing in the `Node.js 10` runtime. This bug report contains a lot of additional pointers: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/437

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue last year, probably you are missing some permission, I would do it this way, hope this works for you:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import { auth } from 'google-auth-library'

export const generateBackup = async () => {
  const client = await auth.getClient({
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    ]
  })

  const path = `YOUR_FOLDER_NAME_FOR_THE_BACKUP`
  const BUCKET_NAME = `YOUR_BUCKET_NAME_HERE`

  const projectId = await auth.getProjectId()
  const url = `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/${projectId}/databases/(default):exportDocuments`
  const backup_route = `gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/${path}`

  return client.request({
    url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        outputUriPrefix: backup_route,
        // collectionsIds: [] // if you want to specify which collections to export, none means all
    }
  })
  .catch(async (e) => {
    return Promise.reject({ message: e.message })
  })

}
```

You can then decide that is your trigger for this function and execute it accordingly.

Note: Go to the IAM section of your project and find the App Engine service account, you will need to add the role `Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin`, otherwise, It will fail.

You can read more about it [here](https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/firebase-cloud-functions-automated-backups/) It's very detailed.

Cheers.